# Need advice on size of Root Partition for latest Ubuntu or Ubuntu clone distro?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, root, ntfs

I have two Hard Drives a Samsung 750Gigs and a Western Digital Green 2 TB.
My current partition scheme consists of only 3 NTFS partitions:

750:
   C: 75 Gigs  Windows 7 Home Premium
   D: 675 Gigs for Games and other stuff

2000:
   E: 2 TB for remaining storage

and 4Gigs of RAM

I plan to dual boot Linux Ubuntu or a similar flavor of it (I assume they mostly have the space requirements)

My Question is mainly about the size of the Root partition and maybe also the SWAP partition.
I plan to install a  root  swap and home partition on the 2 TB hard drive and leave the other HDD for windows 7 and windows games. But, I am slowly transitioning to Linux, hopefully completely and want to know how large should be the root partition if I plan to install a lot of software and Linux games from the repositories and maybe sourceforge and other sources so I would not need to resize the root in the foreseeable future ?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I would give 40-50GB for / and mabey 100GB for /home with the rest as an NTFS volume for movies/music/whatever so you can get to it from either OS. Putting /home on it's own partition allows you to upgrade or distro hop without losing all your linux data.